# How to write to a file in the Directory "/sys/....."

Tags: android, permissions, android-ndk, sys

How can i edit the file in the sys directory using JNI and NDk in android.
Actually i Need to edit these file `"/sys/class/gpio/gpio41/value"`.

Comment: NDK or not, this is not doable on a non-rooted device. Once the device is rooted, however, it's regular file I/O. Are you stuck on the latter?

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev By changing the mode I can nw edit the file using:      chmod 777 /sys/class/gpio/gpio41/value

Comment: OK, so what's your question now? By the way, when the situation changes, it's better to edit the question rather than write comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the mode you can now edit the file using: chmod 777 /sys/class/gpio/gpio41/value

Answer (score 0):

just a little hint: use chmod 666 ...
You will get read/write permission but you don't need execute permission on
HW-pins.

Regards
Martin